# The graph of $x^e$ and why is not defined on $R$?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

I am having trouble understanding the $x^e$ function. Indeed, I cannot draw it with my software, it only offers me a graph on $R^+$. This function is however defined on any $R$?

Is this because $e$ is irrational?

I tried to understand why, I thought maybe if we consider that $x$ as $e^{\log(x)}$, then it must not work for $x<0$? but when I do $e^{-12}$ I get a real value of $6.14421\times10^{-6}$

Comment: Sorry, it's about $e^x$

Comment: True, we run into certain troubles with $x^e$ when $x$ is negative, and that's because $e$ is irrational.

Comment: Can you please explain me ?

Comment: $6.14421\cdot10^{-6}$ is not $(-12)^e$, but $e^{-12}$.

Comment: yes this is an another error

Comment: @lonestudent Ok this is true if we let $x=e^{\log{x}}$, but why Mathematica compute this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation $x^e$ does not produce real values when $x<0$.  (There is a problem even with $(-1)^{1/2}$, which you may already have seen.)  With some effort, we can interpret $x^e$ as a complex multi-valued function.

See [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html)

Comment: Thank you. @GEdgar. Is $x^e$ well defined on $0$ ? or there is a continuous extention at $0$ ? I m asking this quesstion because I see $x$ as $e^{\log(x)}$ and by the way we cannot defined the function at $0$

Comment: Every branch of $x^e$ satisfies $|x^e| = |x|^e$, so we could say that $0^e = 0$.  [The indeterminate form here is $0^0$ with exponent $0$.]

Comment: Thank. This is not clear for me. Can I say that the domain of definition of $x^e$ is $]0,+\infty[ $ or $[0,+\infty[$ ? 0 included ? what's is the formal definition of this function ?